# Chrome, Firefox adding extra <br>

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox

When I click view source, the HTML on my page is

[image: View Source]

but the page has a big gap above the table.  When I Ctrl-Shift-I or view the source code in Chrome or Firefox's developer tools the HTML is

[image: Developer Tools]

How could both browsers' view source be different than the source in the developer tools? Where are those `<br>`s from and how do I remove them?

Searching for `<br>` in the "view source" page says there are no instances in the HTML.

Comment: "View source" will show you the source of the file delivered by the server. Inspecting elements will show you the DOM that the browser has built up. The DOM may be changed by JavaScript for example, but the source file will always remain the same.

Comment: Its possible that you have chrome extension that messing with it. I always have problem like this. Try disabling every extension one by one. See which one is messing around.

Comment: Could you post the whole source? At least the parts needed to re-create?

Answer (score 9):

Good suggestions. Disabling all chrome extensions didn't work and there isn't any javascript that adds 
's.

It turns out the HTML had `<br /><br />` between the table rows:

```
<tr></tr>
<br /><br />
<tr></tr>
```

so the browsers must have rendered them before the table and changed them to `<br>`.

Comment: This sounds like a very likely explanation. Browsers are very forgiving when it comes to HTML, and will always try to draw the page even if the HTML is incorrect (in this case by simply moving the `<br>` tags to somewhere where they are possible to render). `<br>` and `<br />` mean the same thing.

Comment: I just ran into this issue myself, after trying to replace carriage returns in some text with <br />.

Comment: True life-saver. Thank you.

Comment: this took me an hour to find... accidently wrote `<tr>..</br>` instead of `<tr>..</tr>`